# Structuring Databases for Financial Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am looking for the best way to structure my database. I have quarterly financial statements for 1000’s of companies from 1997-2012.  Each company has three different statements, an income statement, a balance sheet, and a cash flow statement.

I want to be able to perform calculations on the data such as adding up each quarter to get a yearly total for each line item on each statement.

I have tried two ways so far:

1)  Storing each line item for each statement in it’s own table i.e. Sales would be one table and have only sales data for all companies I am tracking, with company as the primary key, and each quarters data as a separate column.  This seems like the easiest way to work with the data, but updating the data each quarter is time consuming as there are hundreds of tables.

```
Sales Table
Company q32012  q22012  q12012
ABC Co.  500    100 202
XYZ Co. 230 302 202
```

2) The other option which is a little easier to update but harder to work with the data is to have a separate table for each company for each statement. For example, the income statement for Royal Bank would have it’s own table, with the primary column being the line item.

```
Income Statement for Royal Bank
Line_Item   q32012  q22012  q12012
Sales            
Net Profit
```

The problem here is when I try to annualize this data, I get a really ugly output due to the group by

```
SELECT    
(CASE WHEN Line_Item = 'Sales' THEN SUM(q4 + q3 + q2 + q1) ELSE '0' END) AS Sales2012, 
(CASE WHEN Line_Item = 'NetProfit' THEN SUM(q4 + q3 + q2 + q1) 
      ELSE '0' END) AS Inventories2012
FROM            dbo.[RoyalBankIncomeStatement]
GROUP BY Line_Item
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever I've had to build a database for fiscal reports by fiscal quarter, month, or year or whatever,  I've found it convenient to borrow a concept from star schema design and data warehousing, even if I'm not really building a DW.

The borrowed concept is to have a table, let's call it ALMANAC, that has one row for each date,  keyed by the date.  In this case a natural key works out well.  Dependent attributes in here can be what fiscal month and quarter the date belongs to,  whether the date was one where the enterprise was open for business (TRUE or FALSE), and whatever other quirks are in the company calendar.

Then, you need a computer program that just generates this table out of nothing.  All the strange rules for the company calendar are embedded in this one program.  The ALMANAC can cover a ten year period in a little over 3,650 rows.  That's a tiny table.

Now every date in the operational data can be used like a foreign key into the ALMANAC table, provided you consistently use the Date datatype for dates.  For example,  each sale has a date of sale.  Then aggregating by fiscal quarter, or fiscal year,  or whatever you like is just a matter of joining operational data with the ALMANAC, and using GROUP BY and SUM() to get the aggregate you want.

It's simple, and it makes generating a whole raft of time period reports a breeze.

Answer (score 2):

My advice to you is to think about not using a SQL database to do this.  Instead, think of using something like SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS).  If you want to get a quick start with SSAS, I recommend getting up to speed on PowerPivot for Excel.  You can take the model you develop in PowerPivot and import it into SSAS when you're ready.

Why don't I recommend SQL?  Because you're going to have a problem aggregating accounts in SQL Server.  For example, your balance sheets aren't going to be something you're going to be able to aggregate easily in SQL -- Asking SQL Server for the "Cash" for 2010, for example means that you want to get the entry for the end of December 2010, not that you want to SUM all of the entries for Cash for that year (which would be a nonsense number).   On the other hand, with income and expense accounts such as those which would appear on your income statements, you *would* want to SUM those values up.  To make matters worse, some reports are going to have a mix of account types on them, which is going to make reporting quite difficult.

SSAS has provisions inside the product where it "knows" how to aggregate for your reports based on account type, and there are many tutorials out there which can show you how to set this up.

Either way, you're going to need to store your data somewhere before it goes into your reporting system or Analysis Services cube.  In order to do that, you should structure your data something like this.  Let's say you're storing your data in a table called Reports:

```
Reports
--------
[Effective Date]
[CompanyID]
[AccountID]
[Amount]
```

Your Account table would have the description of what you're trying to store (income, expenses, etc).  Your [Effective Date] column would link back into a `Dates` table which describes to which year, quarter, etc., your data belongs.  In essence, what I'm describing is a classic shape for reporting databases, called a [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

Comment: +1 Dave. This is definitely star schema. A data cube and/or tabular model/PowerPivot will be excellent fit(s) for slicing and dicing by quarter, account, and company and quickly returning results. A proper star schema design is a near per-requisite for these though.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with the following structure in one data table:

```
Company
StatementType 
LineItem
FiscalYear
Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4
```

StatementType would be Income Statement, Balance Sheet or Cash Flow Statement. Line Item would be the coded/uncoded text of the item on the statement, Fiscal Year is 2012, 2011 and so on. You'd still need to make sure that Line Items are consistent across companies.

This structure would let you query for flat statement -

```
select
LineItem, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4
from Data
where 
Company = 'RoyalBank'
and FiscalYear = 2012
and StatementType = 'Income Statement'
```

or

QoQ

```
select
FiscalYear,
Q1
from Data
where 
Company = 'Royal Bank'
and 
StatementType = 'Income Statement'
and
LineItem = 'Sales'
order by FiscalYear
```

in addition to aggregates. You'd probably want to have another table for line items with some kind of an index reference to make sure you can pull the statement back in the original order of line items.

Comment: I am looking into both options recommended.  With SQL, I created a table below with one slight modification recommended (all values in one field vs. each quarter in a separate field). 

Company StatementType  LineItem FiscalYear Quarter Amount
WJX.TO IncomeStatement Sales 2012 Q3 356.4

I can get annual totals no problem.  However, I get a divide by zero error when doing division (i.e annual Profit Margin(NetProfit/Sales). Nullif doesn't help.

Comment: SELECT        Company, FiscalYear, LineItem, (CASE WHEN Company = 'WJX.TO' AND lineitem = 'Earnings' AND fiscalyear = '2011' THEN SUM(amount) ELSE 0 END)  / (CASE WHEN Company = 'WJX.TO' AND lineitem = 'Sales' AND fiscalyear = '2011' THEN SUM(amount) ELSE 0 END) AS ProfitMargin2011
FROM            dbo.FinancialData
WHERE        (StatementType = 'IncomeStatement') AND (Company = 'WJX.TO')
GROUP BY Company, FiscalYear, LineItem
I am going to start looking at PowerPivot/SSAS now as well.
Company StatementType  LineItem FiscalYear Quarter Amount
WJX.TO IncomeStatement Sales  2012  Q3  356.4

Comment: ProfitMargin = case when Sales = 0 then 0 else NetProfit / Sales end