# SQL COUNT zero issue

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I’m having trouble with counting zero values via an SQL Query. Though similar questions have been asked on the site, I can’t seem to get it working with my query.

I have a database including certain strings, such as '{TICKER|IBM}' to which I will refer as ticker-strings. The target is to count the amount of ticker-strings per day.

My database table 'tweets' includes the rows 'tweet_id', 'created at' (dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss) and 'processed text'. The ticker-strings, such as '{TICKER|IBM}', are within the 'processed text' row.

Thus for counting, I made the following SQL query.

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT `tweet_id` ) , DATE( `created_at` )
FROM `tweets`
WHERE `processed_text` LIKE '%{TICKER|IBM}%'
GROUP BY DATE( `tweets`.`created_at` )
```

This query returns the amount of distinct tweet ids per date, but neglects the dates on which the count equals zero. I understand that this can be blamed on not using a 'LEFT JOIN' in my SQL query, but I have still been unable to create a working SQL query for this problem (due to my limited SQL knowledge).

UPDATE thanks to a commenter: I will create a table with the dates (without hh/mm/ss in it). Could someone explain to me how I should link to this table if it is called 'dates'?

Comment: It has nothing to do with using `WHERE`. You can only get data that's actually in the database. You need a table with all the dates, so you can join with that.

Comment: Thanks, I will add a table with all the dates. Could you explain how I should proceed after that?

Comment: Select the dates that you want from the date table, then do a left join on the `tweets` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to left join your date table with the subquery that returns the counts:

```
SELECT d.date, IFNULL(t.count, 0) AS tweet_count
FROM all_dates AS d
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT tweet_id) AS count, DATE(created_at) AS date
    FROM tweets
    WHERE processed_text LIKE '%{TICKER|IBM}%'
    GROUP BY date) AS t
ON d.date = t.date
```

Also, if `tweet_id` is a unique column, you don't need `COUNT(DISTINCT tweet_id)`, just use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Thanks! I am still getting an error on t.count though (unknown column 't.count' in 'field list'

Comment: I forgot to give it an alias

Answer (score 0):

I made a suggestion to create an ALMANAC table in response to a similar question, a few years ago.

[Structuring Databases for Financial Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780436/structuring-databases-for-financial-statements)

An ALMANAC table can be enormously useful in a reporting database, even if it isn't a data mart or a data warehouse.

The best way to generate an ALMANAC table is to write a program, using a regular programming language, or perhaps a procedural extension to SQL.  If you do this, there are some attributes like "Company holiday" (yes/no) or "Fiscal Quarter" (FY2014Q2) that you might find worth while to add, depending on your reporting needs.  Once you have an ALMANAC, Bamar's response using LEFT JOIN should help you.