# Fiscal Year Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, database-design

Our company would like to change the fiscal year calculation on reports from 3/1/17-18  to 1/1/17-18, which would coincide with calendar year.

I am most likely going to submit this to the consultant that originally designed the query to bring data from a table in another DB to a table and view in the reporting db but I would like to get a better understanding of the query (see attached).

Do I need to change the Month to 1 on all date related statements or just on the Fiscal Year statement?

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Thank you so much.

```
USE [ABC_Cube]
GO
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[ABC_Fact]    Script Date: 04/06/2017          
11:28:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER view [dbo].[ABC_Fact] as 
-- Start Binder Data
Select 
'Binder Record' as RowType
,CASE when b.NewOrRenew ='N' THEN 'New Business' ELSE 'Renewal'  end  as       
RowSubType
,CASE when b.Underwriteruserid IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE   
b.Underwriteruserid END AS userID
,CASE when u.username IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE u.username END  AS username
,CASE when B.ACCOUNTID IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE B.ACCOUNTID END  AS 
ACCOUNTID
,CASE when a.account IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE a.account END as Agency
,CASE when ad.CITY IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.CITY END as CITY
,CASE when ad.state IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.state END as State
,CASE when ad.POSTALCODE IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.POSTALCODE END as ZIP
,CASE when ad.COUNTRY IS NULL THEN 'US' ELSE ad.state END as COUNTRY
,CASE when c.ContactID IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE c.ContactID END as 
contactID
,CASE when c.firstname+' '+c.lastname IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE 
c.firstname+' '+c.lastname END as Agent
,b.HouseNumber as House
,B.DEPTARTMENTCODE
,co.companycode
,coalesce(co.companyname1,'')+' '+coalesce(co.companyname2,'')+' 
('+co.companycode+')' as CompanyName
,b.SubmissionNumber 
,b.Underwriter
,b.Insured1
,b.PolicyTypeCode
,b.Submissioncreatedate as SubmitDate
,month(b.Submissioncreatedate) as Submit_Month
,year(b.Submissioncreatedate) as Submit_Year
,b.FirstQuoteDate
,month(b.FirstQuoteDate) as FirstQuote_Month
,year(b.FirstQuoteDate) as FirstQuote_Year
,b.BoundDate
,month(b.BoundDate) as Bound_Month
,year(b.BoundDate) as Bound_Year
,b.PolicyEffectiveDate
,month(b.PolicyEffectiveDate) as Effective_Month
,year(b.PolicyEffectiveDate) as Effective_Year
,case when (month(b.PolicyEffectiveDate)<=3) then 
year(b.PolicyEffectiveDate)-1 else year(b.PolicyEffectiveDate) end as 
Effective_FiscalYear
,b.PolicyExpirationDate
,month(b.PolicyExpirationDate) as Expiration_Month
,year(b.PolicyExpirationDate) as Expiration_Year
,case when (month(b.PolicyExpirationDate)<=3) then 
year(b.PolicyExpirationDate)-1 else year(b.PolicyExpirationDate) end as 
Expiration_FiscalYear
,CASE when b.LOBCode  IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE b.LOBCode end as LOBCode
,CASE when b.LOBName  IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE b.LOBName end as LOBName
,CASE when B.LOBClass IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE B.LOBClass end as LOBClass
,CASE when b.IndustryDOBCode  IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE b.IndustryDOBCode 
end AS DOBCode 
,CASE when b.IndustryDOBName IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE b.IndustryDOBName 
end AS DOBName 
,CASE when B.IndustryDOBClass IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE B.IndustryDOBClass  
end as DOBClass 
,case 
    when SubmissionStatusCode='SUB' then 'Submitted'
    when SubmissionStatusCode='QUO' then 'Quoted'
    when SubmissionStatusCode='BIN' then 'Bound'
    when SUBSTRING(SubmissionStatusCode,1,1)='T' then 'Termintated'
    else 'Other'
end SubmissionStatus
,SubmissionStatusCode
,case when (FIRSTQUOTEDATE is not null or submissionstatuscode = 'BIN')  
then 'Y' else 'N' end Quoted
,0 AS ActivityCounter
,CASE when b.ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
b.ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium END AS ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium
,1 SubCounter
,CurrentPremium SubDol
,case when (FIRSTQUOTEDATE is not null or submissionstatuscode = 'BIN') 
then 1 else 0 end QuoteCounter
,case when (FIRSTQUOTEDATE is not null or submissionstatuscode = 'BIN') 
then CurrentPremium else 0 end QuoteDol
,case when SubmissionStatusCode='BIN' then 1 else 0 end BoundCounter
,case when SubmissionStatusCode='BIN' then CurrentPremium else 0 end 
BoundDol
,case when SUBSTRING(SubmissionStatusCode,1,1)='T' then 1 else 0 end 
TerminateCounter
,case when SUBSTRING(SubmissionStatusCode,1,1)='T' then CurrentPremium 
else 0 end TerminateDol
,case when b.CURRENTHOUSECOMMISSION IS not NULL then 
CURRENTHOUSECOMMISSION else 0 end SubCommission
,case when (FIRSTQUOTEDATE is not null or submissionstatuscode = 'BIN') 
and b.CURRENTHOUSECOMMISSION IS not NULL then CURRENTHOUSECOMMISSION else 
0 end QuoteCommission
,case when SubmissionStatusCode='BIN' and b.CURRENTHOUSECOMMISSION IS not 
NULL then CURRENTHOUSECOMMISSION else 0 end BoundCommission
,case when SUBSTRING(SubmissionStatusCode,1,1)='T' then 
CURRENTHOUSECOMMISSION else 0 end TerminateCommission
-- Projected
,0 AS Projected_ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium
,0 AS Projected_SubCounter
,0 AS Projected_SubDol
,0 AS Projected_QuoteCounter
,0 AS Projected_QuoteDol
,0 AS Projected_BoundCounter
,0 AS Projected_BoundDol
,0 AS Projected_TerminateCounter
,0 AS Projected_TerminateDol
,0 AS Projected_SubCommission
,0 AS Projected_QuoteCommission
,0 AS Projected_BoundCommission
,0 AS Projected_TerminateCommission

from ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.c_Binder b
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.account a on a.accountid =b.accountid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.address ad on ad.addressid =a.addressid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.Contact c on c.contactid =b.contactid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.USERInfo u on u.userid  =b.Underwriteruserid
left join company co on co.companycode=b.companycode
union all
-- New Business Projections
Select 
'Projection' as RowType
,'New Business' as RowSubType
,up.userID
,u.username
,'N/A' AS ACCOUNTID
,'N/A' AS Agency
,'N/A' AS  CITY
,'N/A' AS State
,'N/A' AS ZIP
,'N/A' AS COUNTRY
,'N/A' AS contactID
,'N/A' Agent
,coalesce(substring(u.division,1,2),'N/A')  AS House
,'N/A' AS DEPTARTMENTCODE
,'N/A' AS companycode
,'N/A' AS CompanyName
,'N/A' AS SubmissionNumber 
,up.usertext1 AS Underwriter
,'N/A' AS Insured1
,'N/A' AS PolicyTypeCode
,case when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())<=3) or (mn.month>3 and    
month(getdate())>3) 
         then 
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000),1)
     when (mn.month>3 and month(getdate())<=3) 
         THEN 
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000-
1),1)
     when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())>3) 
         THEN 

convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000+1),
1) end as SubmitDate,mn.month as Submit_Month
,case when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())<=3) or (mn.month>3 and    
month(getdate())>3) 

convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000+1),
1) end as SubmitDate,mn.month as Submit_Month
,case when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())<=3) or (mn.month>3 and
 month(getdate())>3)
 then YEAR(getdate())
     when (mn.month>3 and month(getdate())<=3) 
         THEN YEAR(getdate())-1
     when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())>3) 
         THEN YEAR(getdate())+1
end as Submit_Year
,case when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())<=3) or (mn.month>3 and  
month(getdate())>3) 
         then 
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000),1)
     when (mn.month>3 and month(getdate())<=3) 
         THEN  
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000- 
1),1)
     when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())>3) 
         THEN    
 convert(datetime,mn.month+"/01/"convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000+1),
 1) end as FirstQuoteDate
,mn.month as FirstQuote_Month
,case when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())<=3) or (mn.month>3 and  
month(getdate())>3) 
         then YEAR(getdate())
     when (mn.month>3 and month(getdate())<=3) 
         THEN YEAR(getdate())-1
     when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())>3) 
         THEN YEAR(getdate())+1
end as FirstQuote_Year
,case when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())<=3) or (mn.month>3 and 
month(getdate())>3) 
         then  
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000),1)
     when (mn.month>3 and month(getdate())<=3) 
         THEN  
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000-
1),1)
     when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())>3) 
         THEN 
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000+1),
1)end as BoundDate
,mn.month as Bound_Month
,case when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())<=3) or (mn.month>3 and 
month(getdate())>3) 
         then YEAR(getdate())
     when (mn.month>3 and month(getdate())<=3) 
         THEN YEAR(getdate())-1
     when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())>3) 
         THEN YEAR(getdate())+1
end as Bound_Year
    ,case when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())<=3) or (mn.month>3 and  
month(getdate())>3) 
         then  
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000),1)
     when (mn.month>3 and month(getdate())<=3) 
         THEN  
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000-
1),1)
     when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())>3) 
         THEN  
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000+1),   
1)
end as PolicyEffectiveDate
,mn.month as Effective_Month
,case when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())<=3) or (mn.month>3 and   
month(getdate())>3) 
         then YEAR(getdate())
     when (mn.month>3 and month(getdate())<=3) 
         THEN YEAR(getdate())-1
     when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())>3) 
         THEN YEAR(getdate())+1
end as Effective_Year
,case when (Month(GETDATE())<=3)
    then YEAR(getdate())-1
    else
        YEAR(getdate())
    end
as  Effective_FiscalYear
,case when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())<=3) or (mn.month>3 and  
month(getdate())>3) 
         then   
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000+1),     
1) when (mn.month>3 and month(getdate())<=3) 
THEN  
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000),1)
 when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())>3) 
         THEN   
convert(datetime,mn.month+'/01/'+convert(char(4),YEAR(getdate())-2000+2),    
1)
end as PolicyExpirationDate
,mn.month as Expiration_Month
,case when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())<=3) or (mn.month>3 and  
month(getdate())>3) 
         then YEAR(getdate())+1
     when (mn.month>3 and month(getdate())<=3) 
         THEN YEAR(getdate())
     when (mn.month<=3 and month(getdate())>3) 
         THEN YEAR(getdate())+2
end as Expiration_Year
,case when (Month(GETDATE())<=3)
        then YEAR(getdate())
        else
            YEAR(getdate())+1
        end
    as  Expiration_FiscalYear
,'N/A' AS LOBCode
,'N/A' AS LOBName
,'N/A' AS LOBClass
,'N/A' AS DOBCode
,'N/A' AS DOBName
,'N/A' AS DOBClass
,'Bound' AS  SubmissionStatus
,'BIN' AS SubmissionStatusCode
,'Y' as Quoted
,0 AS ActivityCounter   
---- Actual
,0 AS ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium
,0 AS SubCounter
,0 AS SubDol
,0 AS QuoteCounter
,0 AS QuoteDol
,0 AS BoundCounter
,0 as BoundDol
,0 AS TerminateCounter
,0 AS TerminateDol
,0 AS SubCommission
,0 AS QuoteCommission
,0 AS BoundCommission
,0 AS TerminateCommission
-- Projected
,0 AS Projected_ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium
,0 AS Projected_SubCounter
,0 AS Projected_SubDol
,0 AS Projected_QuoteCounter
,0 AS Projected_QuoteDol
,0 AS Projected_BoundCounter
,CASE when up.USERNUM1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE (up.USERNUM1/12) END AS  
Projected_BoundDol
,0 AS Projected_TerminateCounter
,0 AS Projected_TerminateDol
,0 AS Projected_SubCommission
,0 AS Projected_QuoteCommission
,(up.USERNUM1/12)*up.usernum2 AS Projected_BoundCommission
,0 AS Projected_TerminateCommission
from ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.USERPROFILE up 
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.USERInfo u on u.userid = up.userid
join dbo.MonthNumber mn on 1=1
where up.usertext1 is not null AND up.usernum1 is not null AND   
up.usernum1>0
-- Renewal Bussness Projections
UNION ALL
Select 
'Projection' as RowType
,'Renewal'  as RowSubType
,CASE when b.Underwriteruserid IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE 
b.Underwriteruserid END AS userID
,CASE when u.username IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE u.username END  AS username
,CASE when B.ACCOUNTID IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE B.ACCOUNTID END  AS 
ACCOUNTID
,CASE when a.account IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE a.account END as Agency
,CASE when ad.CITY IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.CITY END as CITY
,CASE when ad.state IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.state END as State
,CASE when ad.POSTALCODE IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.POSTALCODE END as ZIP
,CASE when ad.COUNTRY IS NULL THEN 'US' ELSE ad.state END as COUNTRY
,CASE when c.ContactID IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE c.ContactID END as 
contactID
,CASE when c.firstname+' '+c.lastname IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE  
c.firstname+' '+c.lastname END as Agent
,b.HouseNumber as House
,B.DEPTARTMENTCODE
,co.companycode
,coalesce(co.companyname1,'')+' '+coalesce(co.companyname2,'')+' 
('+co.companycode+')' as CompanyName
,b.SubmissionNumber 
,b.Underwriter
,b.Insured1
,b.PolicyTypeCode
,DATEADD(YYYY,1,b.Submissioncreatedate) as SubmitDate
,month(DATEADD(YYYY,1,b.Submissioncreatedate)) as Submit_Month
,year(DATEADD(YYYY,1,b.Submissioncreatedate)) as Submit_Year
,DATEADD(YYYY,1,b.FirstQuoteDate) AS FirstQuoteDate
,month(DATEADD(YYYY,1,b.FirstQuoteDate)) as FirstQuote_Month
,year(DATEADD(YYYY,1,b.FirstQuoteDate)) as FirstQuote_Year
,DATEADD(YYYY,1,b.BoundDate) AS BoundDate
,month(DATEADD(YYYY,1,b.BoundDate)) as Bound_Month
,year(DATEADD(YYYY,1,b.BoundDate)) as Bound_Year
,DATEADD(YYYY,1,b.PolicyEffectiveDate) as PolicyEffectiveDate
,month(b.PolicyEffectiveDate) as Effective_Month 
,year(b.PolicyEffectiveDate)+1 as Effective_Year
,case when (month(b.PolicyEffectiveDate))<=3 then 
year(b.PolicyEffectiveDate) else  year(b.PolicyEffectiveDate)+1 end as  
Effective_FiscalYear
,DATEADD(YYYY,1,b.PolicyExpirationDate) as PolicyExpirationDate
,month(b.PolicyExpirationDate) as  Expiration_Month
,year(b.PolicyExpirationDate)+1 as  Expiration_Year
,case when (month(b.PolicyExpirationDate))<=3 then 
year(b.PolicyExpirationDate) else  year(b.PolicyExpirationDate)+1 end as 
Expiration_FiscalYear
,CASE when b.LOBCode  IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE b.LOBCode end as LOBCode
,CASE when b.LOBName  IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE b.LOBName end as LOBName
,CASE when B.LOBClass IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE B.LOBClass end as LOBClass
,CASE when b.IndustryDOBCode  IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE b.IndustryDOBCode 
end AS DOBCode 
,CASE when b.IndustryDOBName IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE b.IndustryDOBName  
end AS DOBName 
,CASE when B.IndustryDOBClass IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE B.IndustryDOBClass   
end as DOBClass 
,case 
    when SubmissionStatusCode='SUB' then 'Submitted'
    when SubmissionStatusCode='QUO' then 'Quoted'
    when SubmissionStatusCode='BIN' then 'Bound'
    when SUBSTRING(SubmissionStatusCode,1,1)='T' then 'Termintated'
    else 'Other'
end SubmissionStatus
,SubmissionStatusCode
,case when (FIRSTQUOTEDATE is not null or submissionstatuscode = 'BIN')   
then 'Y' else 'N' end Quoted
,0 AS ActivityCounter
---- Actual
,0 AS ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium
,0 AS SubCounter
,0 AS SubDol
,0 AS QuoteCounter
,0 AS QuoteDol
,0 AS BoundCounter
,0 as BoundDol
,0 AS TerminateCounter
,0 AS TerminateDol
,0 AS SubCommission
,0 AS QuoteCommission
,0 AS BoundCommission
,0 AS TerminateCommission
--- Projected
,CASE when b.CurrentPremium IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE b.CurrentPremium END AS  
Projected_ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium
,0 as Projected_SubCounter
,0 as Projected_SubDol
,0 AS Projected_QuoteCounter
,0 AS Projected_QuoteDol
,case when SubmissionStatusCode='BIN' then 1*up.usernum3 else 0 end AS  
Projected_BoundCounter
,case when SubmissionStatusCode='BIN' then CurrentPremium*up.usernum3   
else 0 end AS Projected_BoundDol
,0 as Projected_TerminateCounter
,0 as Projected_TerminateDol
,0 AS Projected_SubCommission
,0 AS Projected_QuoteCommission
,case when SubmissionStatusCode='BIN' and b.CURRENTHOUSECOMMISSION IS not  
NULL then CURRENTHOUSECOMMISSION*up.usernum3 else 0 end AS   
Projected_BoundCommission
,0 AS Projected_TerminateCommission
from ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.c_Binder b
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.account a on a.accountid =b.accountid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.address ad on ad.addressid =a.addressid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.Contact c on c.contactid =b.contactid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.USERInfo u on u.userid  =b.Underwriteruserid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.USERPROFILE up on uP.userid  =b.Underwriteruserid
left join company co on co.companycode=b.companycode
where up.usertext1 is not null AND up.usernum3 is not null AND   
up.usernum3>0
and case when (month(b.PolicyEffectiveDate))<=3 then  
year(b.PolicyEffectiveDate) else  year(b.PolicyEffectiveDate)+1 end 
= case when (Month(GETDATE())<=3)
then YEAR(getdate())-1
else
    YEAR(getdate())
end
Union all
-- Open Activity Data
Select 
'Open Activity' as RowType
,at.atype as RowSubType
,CASE when h.userID IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE h.userID END AS userID
,CASE when u.username IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE u.username END  AS username
,CASE when h.ACCOUNTID IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE h.ACCOUNTID END  AS 
ACCOUNTID
,CASE when a.account IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE a.account END as Agency
,CASE when ad.CITY IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.CITY END as CITY
,CASE when ad.state IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.state END as State
,CASE when ad.POSTALCODE IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.POSTALCODE END as ZIP
,CASE when ad.COUNTRY IS NULL THEN 'US' ELSE ad.state END as COUNTRY
,CASE when c.ContactID IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE c.ContactID END as  
contactID
,CASE when c.firstname+' '+c.lastname IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE  
c.firstname+' '+c.lastname END as Agent
,coalesce(substring(u.division,1,2),'N/A')  AS House
,'N/A' AS DEPTARTMENTCODE
,'N/A' AS companycode
,'N/A' AS CompanyName
,'N/A' AS SubmissionNumber 
,up.usertext1 AS Underwriter
,'N/A' AS Insured1
,'N/A' as PolicyTypeCode
,h.startdate as SubmitDate
,month(h.startdate) as Submit_Month
,year(h.startdate) as Submit_Year
,h.startdate as FirstQuoteDate
,month(h.startdate) as FirstQuote_Month
,year(h.startdate) as FirstQuote_Year
,h.startdate as BoundDate
,month(h.startdate) as Bound_Month
,year(h.startdate) as  Bound_Year
,h.startdate as PolicyEffectiveDate
,month(h.startdate) as Effective_Month
,year(h.startdate) as Effective_Year
,case when (month(h.startdate)<=3) then year(h.startdate)-1 else 
year(h.startdate) end as Effective_FiscalYear
,h.startdate as PolicyExpirationDate
,month(h.startdate) as Expiration_Month
,year(h.startdate) as Expiration_Year
,case when (month(h.startdate)<=3) then year(h.startdate)-1 else 
year(h.startdate) end as Expiration_FiscalYear
,'N/A' AS LOBCode
,'N/A' AS LOBName
,'N/A' AS LOBClass
,'N/A' AS DOBCode
,'N/A' AS DOBName
,'N/A' AS DOBClass
,'N/A' AS  SubmissionStatus
,'N/A' AS SubmissionStatusCode
,'N/A' as Quoted
,1 AS ActivityCounter
,0 AS ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium
,0 AS SubCounter
,0 AS SubDol
,0 AS QuoteCounter
,0 AS QuoteDol
,0 AS BoundCounter
,0 AS BoundDol
,0 AS TerminateCounter
,0 AS TerminateDol
,0 AS SubCommission
,0 AS QuoteCommission
,0 AS BoundCommission
,0 AS TerminateCommission
-- Projected
,0 AS Projected_ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium
,0 AS Projected_SubCounter
,0 AS Projected_SubDol
,0 AS Projected_QuoteCounter
,0 AS Projected_QuoteDol
,0 AS Projected_BoundCounter
,0 AS Projected_BoundDol
,0 AS Projected_TerminateCounter
,0 AS Projected_TerminateDol
,0 AS Projected_SubCommission
,0 AS Projected_QuoteCommission
,0 AS Projected_BoundCommission
,0 AS Projected_TerminateCommission
from ABCXYZ.sysdba.activity h
join (select pld.ID as Type,pld.TEXT as AType 
    from ABCXYZ.sysdba.PICKLIST pld
    join  ABCXYZ.sysdba.PICKLIST plh on plh.itemid=pld.PICKLISTID
    where plh.PICKLISTID='PICKLISTLIST' and plh.TEXT='Activity Types') AT    
on h.TYPE=AT.Type
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.account a on a.accountid =h.accountid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.address ad on ad.addressid =a.addressid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.Contact c on c.contactid =h.contactid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.USERPROFILE up on up.userid =h.userID
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.USERInfo u on u.userid  =h.userID
Union all
 -- Completed Activity Data

 Select 
'Completed  Activity' as RowType
,at.atype as RowSubType
,CASE when h.userID IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE h.userID END AS userID
,CASE when u.username IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE u.username END  AS username
,CASE when h.ACCOUNTID IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE h.ACCOUNTID END  AS 
ACCOUNTID
,CASE when a.account IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE a.account END as Agency
,CASE when ad.CITY IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.CITY END as CITY
,CASE when ad.state IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.state END as State
,CASE when ad.POSTALCODE IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE ad.POSTALCODE END as ZIP
,CASE when ad.COUNTRY IS NULL THEN 'US' ELSE ad.state END as COUNTRY
,CASE when c.ContactID IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE c.ContactID END as 
contactID
,CASE when c.firstname+' '+c.lastname IS NULL THEN 'N/A' ELSE 
c.firstname+' '+c.lastname END as Agent
,coalesce(substring(u.division,1,2),'N/A')  AS House
,'N/A' AS DEPTARTMENTCODE
,'N/A' AS companycode
,'N/A' AS CompanyName
,'N/A' AS SubmissionNumber 
,up.usertext1 AS Underwriter
,'N/A' AS Insured1
,'N/A' as PolicyTypeCode
,h.COMPLETEDDATE as SubmitDate
,month(h.COMPLETEDDATE) as Submit_Month
,year(h.COMPLETEDDATE) as Submit_Year
,h.COMPLETEDDATE as FirstQuoteDate
,month(h.COMPLETEDDATE) as FirstQuote_Month
,year(h.COMPLETEDDATE) as FirstQuote_Year
,h.COMPLETEDDATE as BoundDate
,month(h.COMPLETEDDATE) as Bound_Month
,year(h.COMPLETEDDATE) as Bound_Year

,h.COMPLETEDDATE as PolicyEffectiveDate
,month(h.COMPLETEDDATE) as Effective_Month
,year(h.COMPLETEDDATE) as Effective_Year
,case when (month(h.COMPLETEDDATE)<=3) then year(h.COMPLETEDDATE)-1 else 
year(h.COMPLETEDDATE) end as Effective_FiscalYear
,h.COMPLETEDDATE as PolicyExpirationDate
,month(h.COMPLETEDDATE) as Expiration_Month
,year(h.COMPLETEDDATE) as Expiration_Year
,case when (month(h.COMPLETEDDATE)<=3) then year(h.COMPLETEDDATE)-1 else  
year(h.COMPLETEDDATE) end as Expiration_FiscalYear
,'N/A' AS LOBCode
,'N/A' AS LOBName
,'N/A' AS LOBClass
,'N/A' AS DOBCode
,'N/A' AS DOBName
,'N/A' AS DOBClass
,'N/A' AS  SubmissionStatus
,'N/A' AS SubmissionStatusCode
,'N/A' as Quoted
,1 AS ActivityCountera
,0 AS ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium
,0 AS SubCounter
,0 AS SubDol
,0 AS QuoteCounter
,0 AS QuoteDol
,0 AS BoundCounter
,0 AS BoundDol
,0 AS TerminateCounter
,0 AS TerminateDol
,0 AS SubCommission
,0 AS QuoteCommission
,0 AS BoundCommission
,0 AS TerminateCommission
-- Projected
,0 AS Projected_ExpSubmissionPolicyPremium
,0 AS Projected_SubCounter
,0 AS Projected_SubDol
,0 AS Projected_QuoteCounter
,0 AS Projected_QuoteDol
,0 AS Projected_BoundCounter
,0 AS Projected_BoundDol
,0 AS Projected_TerminateCounter
,0 AS Projected_TerminateDol
,0 AS Projected_SubCommission
,0 AS Projected_QuoteCommission
,0 AS Projected_BoundCommission
,0 AS Projected_TerminateCommission
from ABCXYZ.sysdba.history h
join (select pld.ID as Type,pld.TEXT as AType 
    from ABCXYZ.sysdba.PICKLIST pld
    join  ABCXYZ.sysdba.PICKLIST plh on plh.itemid=pld.PICKLISTID
    where plh.PICKLISTID='PICKLISTLIST' and plh.TEXT='Activity Types') AT   
on h.TYPE=AT.Type
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.account a on a.accountid =h.accountid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.address ad on ad.addressid =a.addressid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.Contact c on c.contactid =h.contactid
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.USERPROFILE up on up.userid =h.userID
left join ABCXYZ.SYSDBA.USERInfo u on u.userid  =h.userID
```

Comment: I can't see anything attached.

Comment: Sorry - it should be now.

Comment: Here's a sugestion, from a while back.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780436/structuring-databases-for-financial-statements/13785362#13785362